# Why doesn't the 'setInterval()' call stop?

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

I have gone through other SO questions about this topic and tried the solutions. I cannot find the error. So I presume, it must be an obvious mistake. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var interval = 0; 

function repeat(time, bool) {
    var interval = setInterval(choose, time * 1000);

    function stopRepeat () {

        console.log("im trying to stop");
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    if (bool) {
        stopRepeat();
    }
}
```

The "im trying to stop" is being logged. So it means that the `clearInterval()` is what is not working. I have also tried to call it window.interval but that does not make a difference.

I have also logged the interval after it is supposed to clear and it just results in the same interval rather than a cleared one.

Thanks!

Comment: `stopRepeat` being *inside* of the `repeat` function is pretty confusing - can you post more of your *actual* code without stuff edited out for a clearer picture of what's going on?

Comment: how did you call `repeat` and `choose`

Comment: You only check for bool once, immediately after seeing yo the interval function.

Comment: If you call repeat again with a truthy bool value you'll create a new interval and clear it immediately, because you're referencing the interval within the repeat function, and that value is a new one every time you call repeat. It's quite odd as written.

Comment: Even if it's a global value you'd lose the previously-created interval because you overwrite it as soon as you call repeat. It's not terribly clear what you're actually trying to do here.

Comment: Read about [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So im going to first analyze your code with comments.

```
/*
* First this declaration (var interval=0) is redundant as it is re-declared in the 
* repeat function
*/
var interval = 0; 

function repeat(time, bool) {
    var interval = setInterval(choose, time * 1000);

    function stopRepeat () {

        console.log("im trying to stop");
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    /*
    * Lets assume bool is true.
    * StopRepeat is called immediately and your interval function never gets 
    * to execute nor does your choose function even gets called.

    * Now lets assume bool is even false.
    * StopRepeat never gets called and there is not way of clearing the interval
    */
    if (bool) {
        stopRepeat();
    }
}
```

There are many ways to try this, i'll do a little modification.

```
var choose = function(){
  console.log("choose was called!");
}

function repeat(time, timesToRun=1) {
    var count = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
      choose();
      if(count===timesToRun/*Or a better condition to stop the interval*/){
        console.log("Clearing my intervals");
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
      count++;
    }, time * 1000);
}

repeat(5, 2);
```